# TelegramBot application stop working with this errors (SocketException,IOException,WebException,HttpRequestException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram-bot

I don't know what can i do.My telegrambot project suddenly stop working after about 1 day.with this errors.
please help me,if possible.

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)

Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)

Exception Info: System.Net.WebException
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(System.IAsyncResult)

Exception Info: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResult() at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient+<SendWebRequestAsync>d__1091[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()

Exception Info: System.AggregateException
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResultCore(Boolean) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Result()
at Mybot.BotForm.RunBot()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Just `try` `catch`, and ignore error, it's cause by long polling fail

Comment: @Sean Thanks for your reply.I changed my code,it's work now with no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because of your pooling way. probably your application is out of memory or network connections. you can simply ignore this exception and your operation system will handle it but  if you plan to use this as your long poling method, you should carefully dispose the objects after each request. 
i strongly suggest to use webhook instead of get updates method. its so much faster and efficient.

Comment: Thanks @David for your reply.My Bot project is a .net console app.Can i implement webhook in it?

Comment: unfortunately you cant. you should create web api application.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I'll try it .